# What'd be a good open-source database for learning database design? (Designing the DBMS, not normalizing tables/etc)

Tags: c, database, parsing, sqlite, relational-database

As stated in the question, I'm not looking for help on database design in the terms of creating tables, normalization, etc.

As a programming project, I'm looking to write my own DBMS. This is for a learning experience more than anything, so reinventing the wheel is kinda the purpose.

I started my search by looking at SQLite - I found my and old SVN branch from 2001~2004, which is *amazingly* commented, but it's still a lot to digest all at once. But even so, I've been going through it for about an hour or two, and my head is already on hyperdrive with ideas.

So I'm asking here hoping to see if anyone knows of a small and very basic DBMS that I could get some ideas or inspiration from as far as query parsing, storing data, building a search, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: There can not be a small basic full RDBMS. SQL needs a parser (complicated), querya analyzer, storage, indexing engine, transactions to at least some degree. RDBMS are complicated beasts pretty much be definition.

Answer (score 1):

I have been told that the PostgreSQL source code is very well documented and structured. 
But it obviously does not qualify as a "small basic DBMS".

Apart from that the only "small" ones that I'm aware of are Java based DBMS:

- [TinySQL](http://www.jepstone.net/tinySQL/)
- [SmallSQL](http://www.smallsql.de/)

Not sure if a Java based implementation will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There is Edward Sciore's **SimpleDB** (not related to Amazon's SimpleDB), "A Simple Java-Based Multiuser System for Teaching Database Internals". It's in Java, but I think that the ideas will translate fairly easy to C.

From http://www.cs.bc.edu/~sciore/simpledb/intro.html:

> SimpleDB is a multi-user transactional
>   database server written in Java, which
>   interacts with Java client programs
>   via JDBC.  The system is intended for
>   pedagogical use only.  The code is
>   clean and compact.  The APIs are
>   straightforward.  The learning curve
>   is relatively small.  Everything about
>   it is geared towards improving the
>   experience of a database system
>   internals course.  Consequently, the
>   system is intentionally bare-bones. 
>   It implements only a small fraction of
>   SQL and JDBC, and does little or no
>   error checking.  Although it is a
>   great teaching tool, I can't imagine
>   that anyone would want to use it for
>   anything else.

There is a book too:

[Database Design and Implementation](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471757160.html)

Answer (score 1):

As stated previously, SQLite, JavaDB and SimpleDB are good examples. I would add [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/eKvOPB) to the list. Berkleley DB is well documented, has been around for several years, has several available APIs as well as multiple access methods like HASH, QUEUE and RECNO in addition to the traditional B-tree. Berkeley DB is a key/value database library written in C. [Berkeley DB XML](http://bit.ly/dSBLo5) is an XML database library written in C++ on top of Berkeley DB. [Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://bit.ly/dM4Qtw) is a 100% Java key/value database library. All of them are available under a GPL-like license and the source code is included in the [distribution](http://bit.ly/gNWr1C).

Berkeley DB's SQL API incorporates the SQLite API, basically implementing the BDB key/value pair data store underneath the SQLite query layer. Berkeley DB was also the first data storage implementation underneath MySQL, again taking a SQL query layer and storing the data in a simple key/data value data format. It's certainly an interesting way of looking at the problem -- if you have a flexible, fast, scalable, reliable data store, you can then layer any type of API or data representation/abstraction on top of it. This is exactly what Berkeley DB does, providing a choice between the core key/value pair data storage or XML, SQL, Java Collections or a POJO-like Persistence Layer on top of the base key/value pair infrastructure.

Berkeley DB is about as close to a "pure" data storage engine as you're going to find. It makes no assumptions about structure, content or the format of the data being stored. It allows the upper layers to provide those abstractions while the lower layer focused on fast, scalable, reliable storage. That's one of the reasons why Berkeley DB is so widely used -- it's simplicity and focus makes it very fast, reliable and scalable.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the Product Managers for Berkeley DB, so clearly I'm a little biased. But, I've also been working on database products for 25 years and I know a little about DBMS internals. :-)

Good luck in your research.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the Apache Derby database. It's a full fledged RDBMS implementation;
Well, it's written entirely in Java though. 
and, it definitely is not a small and simple implementation. But it can serve as a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a good start. It is as simple as possible (no network layer, simplistic locking, etc), but it understands real SQL, has indexes and constraints, and is implemented in C. Its storage is peculiar, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple relational database system that uses SQL query language then SQLite is it. Keep on reading that code.

But if you are not hung up on fully relational data stores, then google for B+tree source code. The B+tree is the fundamental data structure that allows you to maintain a sorted index on disk, and 15-20 years ago there were several packages of C source code that implemented this. It is much simpler because there is no SQL, and basically two parts, one to manage blocks on the disk and the other to manipulate the B+Tree structure.

Once you understand that, you could go back to the SQLite code and no doubt identify similar modules amidst the rest of the code.

Sometimes the best way to learn is to retrace some historical steps.

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find a package of C source code implementing B+ tree.